# Use of msts for hourly (16 out of 24 hours per day) in tslm

Tags: time-series

I am new to Time series and have basic knowledge only. I am facing following problem. In following dataset “Response” is derived from “InputA/B” for 16 hours ( 8 am – 23 pm) everyday.

To train I tried

Msts_ Response <-  msts(Response, seasonal.periods =c(?,?) ) # do not kow what to put in “?”

Once above is done then use

Fit <- tslm(Msts_ Response ~ InputA + InputB, data = train)

**Could you help in filling “?” and is the approach OK for tslm**

DateHours   Response    InputA  InputB
8/1/2015 10:00  20  43  1
8/1/2015 11:00  28  43  2
8/1/2015 12:00  26  43  2
8/1/2015 13:00  35  44  3
8/1/2015 14:00  21  44  1
8/1/2015 15:00  49  44  3
8/1/2015 16:00  98  45  8
8/1/2015 17:00  33  43  3
8/1/2015 18:00  45  43  3
8/1/2015 19:00  13  42  1
8/1/2015 20:00  8   42  0
8/1/2015 21:00  12  42  1
8/1/2015 22:00  5   42  0
8/1/2015 23:00  5   42  0
8/1/2015 8:00   5   42  0
8/1/2015 9:00   6   42  0
8/2/2015 10:00  4   42  0
8/2/2015 11:00  10  42  1
8/2/2015 12:00  11  43  1
8/2/2015 13:00  11  43  1
8/2/2015 14:00  6   43  0
8/2/2015 15:00  3   42  0
8/2/2015 16:00  5   42  0
8/2/2015 17:00  4   42  0
8/2/2015 18:00  5   43  0
8/2/2015 19:00  4   43  0
8/2/2015 20:00  4   43  0
8/2/2015 21:00  3   43  0
8/2/2015 22:00  4   43  0
8/2/2015 23:00  4   43  0
8/2/2015 8:00   5   42  0
8/2/2015 9:00   4   42  0
8/3/2015 10:00  17  43  1
8/3/2015 11:00  31  44  2
8/3/2015 12:00  37  44  3
8/3/2015 13:00  33  45  2
8/3/2015 14:00  28  45  2
8/3/2015 15:00  48  45  4
8/3/2015 16:00  67  45  5
8/3/2015 17:00  48  45  4
8/3/2015 18:00  85  45  7
8/3/2015 19:00  45  44  4
8/3/2015 20:00  6   43  0
8/3/2015 21:00  4   43  0
8/3/2015 22:00  6   43  0
8/3/2015 23:00  4   43  0
8/3/2015 8:00   5   43  0
8/3/2015 9:00   8   43  0

Comment: What about c(16,16*7)? since one day has 16 hours and one week has 7days*16hours in your case... in that way you assume that the data has a pattern that repeats every day as well as one that repeats every week. when you post a sample data.set i can have look...

Comment: Zoo package is also one of the solution for irregular TS. 

zoo_ Response <- zoo(train$ Response, train$DateHours) 

Now stuck at 
Fit <- tslm(zoo_ Response ~ InputA + InputB, data = train)

Comment: Can you get a bit more specific what the issue is with the tslm? I don't understand what you mean by "irregular TS" - the msts() approach with c(16,16*7) doesn't work?

Comment: Irregular means data having 16 hours per day only. Hence Zoo is suitable. Since Response has to take care of “InputA/B” so that prediction model is built in concept of “zoo_ Response ~ InputA + InputB”.

How can I Train this kind of data and later predict "Response" from unknown data having "DateHour, InputA and Input B" only

Comment: As far as i understand you right you have 16 hours of each day and since you have always exact the same hours you can pretend that a day has only 16hours instead of 24. In that way there is no need for an irregular time series. In case your talking about irregular time series because you have more than just a few days of data and you want to capture different months (29days, 30days, 31day...) i would suggest you use dummies for that. `tslm` is not more than a regular linear regression `lm`. You can start with that: `y <- ts(data, freq=16)` and for the tslm: `fit <- tslm(y ~ season + trend)`

Comment: For capturing the different weekdays i would include dummy variables. In case you have enough data you can also include months as dummies...

Comment: Please use Answer mode so that I can accept as answer. Does dummy addition means adding few rows of non present hours by some criteria (say mean)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand you right you have 16 hours of each day and since you have always exactly the same number of hours you can pretend that a day has only 16 hours instead of 24. In that way there is no need for an irregular time series. In case you are talking about irregular time series because you have more than just a few days of data and you want to capture different months (29days, 30days, 31day...) I would suggest you use dummies for that. `tslm` is not more than a regular linear regression `lm`. 
You can start with that:

```
y <- ts(data, freq=16) 
fit <- tslm(y ~ season + trend)
```

I will expand my answer and show you how to use dummy variables when you upload some sample dataset that I can use as example.

Comment: Clearly the fiction that the clock stops between one day's end and another's start is worth trying, i.e. the overnight gap is just assumed equivalent to 1 hour. But if there is a systematic difference between the two end-points the fiction just won't work. As you imply, we need to look at data to see what works for the OP's case.